# structure tag compatibility in c

Tags: c, struct, c99

I read that starting from C99, two complete `struct`s defined in different files must have same tag to be compatible.

So I wrote the following code:

**file1.c**:

```
/* file1.c */
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct tag1 { int foo; } type1;
type1 a; 
void func(void);

int main() {
    printf("a.foo : %d\n", a.foo); 
    func();
    printf("a.foo : %d\n", a.foo); 
    return 0;
}
```

**file2.c**:

```
/* file2.c */
typedef struct tag2 { int foo; } type2; 
type2 a;
void func(void) {
    a.foo = 100;
}
```

and expected that two `a`'s to be considered different and thus both `printf`'s to print `a.foo : 0` but the output is:

```
a.foo : 0
a.foo : 100
```

Why is this?

Comment: There are only two things it could do:  (1) complain about the structure tag name mismatch or (2) treat them as the same.  It did (2).  It's not worrying about structure tag name mismatches.  It would be very unlikely for it not to complain but to treat them differently somehow.

Comment: but the scope of definitions of a do not conflict why a mismatch?

Comment: There is only one `a`.  It's in the global namespace.  It was defined equivalently in two different files,  and the linker matched them up.  I don't understand the confusion.  It's simple.  Print their addresses from the two files if you don't believe it - they'll be the same.  There can only be one external global variable with a given name.  If you rename one of them to `b` they will no longer be matched up.

Comment: but then what would be the purpose of adding tag compatablity in c99 ? where it makes a different ?

Comment: my purpose was to see the difference between C versions.

Comment: now i understand that it should not print to 0s ,but still why it is'nt giving a name mismatch ? that's what c99 says.

Comment: The linker really only has two choices:  If it has the information, and it's appropriate, it can give an error.  Otherwise it has to match the names up.  So the linker either doesn't think an error is appropriate, or it doesn't have enough information to give an error.  Or both.  But if it doesn't give an error, then it matches the names to the same address in memory.

Comment: Linkers often have very minimal information.  The know the names and generally the sizes of things, their initialization values, their storage class, and a few other things. But they tend not to understand data types.  Try this:  Declare `int a;` in one file and `double a;` in another.  Obviously you'd like an error for that, but `gcc` doesn't give one.  It just matches them to the same storage.

Comment: indeed it does , as well as clang. thanks i got the idea.

Comment: whould you want to write an answer ? your comments make it clear for me that a's in different files are in same global scope. and compilers usually match same named object of differing type into same storage instead of type mismatch. i am new here i dont know how things work here!

Comment: I'm not sure my answer would be complete.  I don't know about the restrictions put in place in C99 regarding structure tag matches.  The thing to keep in mind is this though:  The compiler looks at individual files (and their includes) in isolation, and creates a .o file which contains relocatable machine code and symbol table entries.

Comment: The linker (often invoked by the compiler) combines multiple .o files to produce an executable file.  Linkers have to be able to handle object files produced by different languages, and generally don't know about data types.  They're concerned with names, storage classes, alignment, and so on.

Comment: If you're using `gcc` on a Unix system, then look at he man page for `ld` (the "link editor").  That's the gnu linker, normally invoked by `gcc` although it can also be invoked directly.

Comment: Which `-std` and warning flags did you use? If you aren't at least getting a warning about this, you should turn more warnings on. :)

Comment: The standard only says that the behaviour is undefined — not that the compilation system must detect and report the problem.  See C11 [§6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7), especially ¶1,2.  Note that ¶2 says: _All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined._  Your code invokes undefined behaviour. One possible result is a crash; another is a compiler warning; another is that it works as you expected. C++ provides type-safe linkage for functions (but not variables).

Comment: @Davislor: i used --std=c99 on gcc and -std=c99 in clang

Comment: @jonathan: thanks.so this behaviour is conforming to standard and compilers have decided to use the behaviour of c89. what is difference between unspecified and undefined behaviour ? i thought that undefined behaviour found at compile time must always result in compile error.

Comment: Oh, no. Undefined behavior gives compilers permission to do anything they want with the code, no matter what bugs it causes. For example, any time you add two `int` variables that *might* overflow or underflow, that’s potential undefined behavior, and your compiler isn’t going to warn you about it every single time. Why is that “undefined?” Some CPUs historically did different things when that happened, and the committee decided that it wanted to allow the behavior to be non-portable, so programs could be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regard to the type issue, the rules in the C standard amount to this:

- **If** you declare `a` using the same structure tag in both files, **then** your program will work (in this regard).

Note that the C standard does not say what will happen if the “If” part is violated. In that case, the C standard does not say your program will work, it does not say your program will not work, it does not say there will be an error message, it does not say there will not be an error message. It simply says nothing.

There is another issue in the program: `type1 a;` and `type2 a;` are *tentative definitions* of `a` which are, according to the C standard, resolve to definitions. Then `a` is defined in multiple translation units, which violates C 2018 6.9 5:

> …  If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression (other than as part of the operand of a `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator whose result is an integer constant), somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one.

However, let’s assume your C implementation defines these to resolve these to a single object, as implementations of C on Unix commonly do. We will consider only the type issue.

Then you are accessing the object `a` with two incompatible types. This violates C 2018 6.5 7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:…

where none of the listed types are satisfied in this case. C 2018 4 2 tells us what the consequence for this violation is:

> If a "shall" or "shall not" requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined…

And C 2018 3.4.3 tells us what that means:

> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this document imposes no requirements

That is it: Due to the type violation, the C standard imposes no requirements on the C implementation. The standard permits your implementation (the compiler, linker, library, operating system, hardware, and anything else needed to build and run C programs) to accept your program, reject your program, run your program, refuse to run your program, warn you, not warn you, let your program misbehave, and more. The standard simply says nothing about what must happen.